# The solution to the integral of $1/(x\ln x-C)$

Tags: integration

Solution to the integral of $$\int \frac{\Bbb dx}{x\ln x-C}$$ where $C>0$ is a constant.

I struggled to solve it but failed. I even doubt whether there is an analytical solution for this question.

The failed attempts are listed below:

1. Assuming $C=0$, it seems quite easy because
   $$\int \frac{\Bbb dx}{x\ln x}=\int \frac{\Bbb d(\ln x)}{\ln x}=\ln(\ln x)$$
   But $C>0$ makes this method less useful because
   $$\int \frac{\Bbb dx}{x\ln x-C}=\int \frac{\Bbb d(\ln x)}{\ln x- \frac{C}{x}}$$
   I don't know how to continue, so I stopped here.
2. Let $y(x)=x\ln x$ and $x(y)=y^{-1} (x)$, the integral becomes
   $$\int \frac{\Bbb dx}{x\ln x-C}=\int \frac{\Bbb d(x(y))}{y-C}$$
   but I guess there is no analytical formula for $x(y)$, so I can't solve $d(x(y))$ so I stopped again.
3. I noticed that
   $$\int \frac{\Bbb dx}{x\ln x-C}=\frac{1}{1-C} \{ \int \frac{\Bbb d(x\ln x-C)}{x\ln x-C} - \int \frac{\Bbb \ln x dx}{x\ln x-C} \} =\frac{1}{1-C} \{ \ln (x\ln x-C) - \int \frac{\Bbb \ln x dx}{x\ln x-C} \}$$
   Again I found that  $\int \frac{\Bbb \ln x dx}{x\ln x-C} $ seems hardly solvable when $C≠0$, so I stopped again.

Sorry for my poor mathematical capability, but I will be grateful if any math expert is willing to provide the solution and solving process.

Comment: Please remember to include your work. Can you explain your failed attempt?

Comment: I do not think there exists a analytical solution to this as per [wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5BDivide%5B1%2CxLog%5Bx%5D-+C%5D%2Cx%5D). Did you check on it or some other mathematical site? It is showing me [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqnwL.png).

Comment: Thanks to the advice from @ElectricShadow , and I add my works on it.

Comment: Thanks to @HamLemon , the solution from wolfram seems daunting! I checked a few other sites but none of them can solve this.

Comment: $$\int \frac{1}{x \log (x)-c} \, dx=\sum _{m=0}^{\infty } -c^{-1-m} (1+m)^{-1-m} \cos (m \pi ) \Gamma (1+m,-((1+m) \log (x)))+C$$ for: $0\leq x\leq 1$

Comment: I agree with @HamLemon ... it is likely that this integral is not an elementary function.

Comment: Thanks to @MariuszIwaniuk . It would be better if the solution can have a simpler form, but at this stage your answer seems the best.

Comment: Thanks to @GEdgar . It indeed seems uneasy to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Writing
$$\frac{1}{x \log (x)-c}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{c^n}{x^{n+1} \log^{n+1} (x)}$$

$$x=e^t \implies I_n=\int \frac{dx}{x^{n+1} \log^{n+1} (x)}=\int e^{-(n-1)t}\,t^{-n}\,dt$$
$$I_n= -t^{-(n-1)} \,E_n((n-1) t)$$ where appear the exponential integral function.

Comment: Thank you so much! It seems an ingenious and neat solution. At this stage I could only comment that the integral seems unsolvable unless we use sum of series.